# How can I load data that comes from a query from the database to get all tags into selectize?

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter, selectize.js

So these past days I've been trying to load data into the selectize.js input, which I've tried many ways and it does not work.

I tried the tags[{}]; way but in only works with strings inside.

```
Example: tags = [
            {text: "science"},
            {text: "biology"},
            {text: "chemistry"},
            {text: "physics"}
         ];
```

```
    <!------ Hidden Input with the tags queried from the database ------>

    <?php 

        $alltags=""; 

        foreach ($tags as $tag ) {

            $alltags.=$tag['name'].".";

        }

    ?>

    <input type="text" style="display:none" value="<?php echo $alltags; ?>" id="hiddeninput_tags">

    <!----------------------------------------------------------------->
```

```
    <!------ JavaScript Function ------>

    function sendtags()
    {

        var rawtags = $('#hiddeninput_tags').val();
        var res = rawtags.split(".");

        res.forEach(function(entry) {

            //alert(tags); If I remove this from comment, when I load the page it will alert all the tags inside the hidden input.

        });

    }

    <!--------------------------------->
```

```
    <!------ Selectize Function ------>

    $('#input-tags').selectize({

        plugins: ['restore_on_backspace', 'remove_button'],
        delimiter: ',',
        persist: false,
        options: tags,
        valueField: 'text',
        create: function(input) {
            return {
                value: input,
                text: input
            }
        },
        render: {

            option_create: function(data, escape) {

                var addString = 'Adicionar';

                return '<div class="create">' + addString + ' <strong>' + escape(data.input) + '</strong>&hellip;</div>';

            }

        }

    });

    <!-------------------------------->
```

I expect the input from selectize to have all the values queried from the database inserted into the value of that "selectize input" so it can suggest the tags that already exist in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @NeonSilver instead of using "" in your string use '' single quotes to make your input value.

Your provide code is displaying like -

```
<input type="text" style="display:block" value="[{text: " science"},{text:="" "biology"},{text:="" "chemistry"},{text:="" "physics"}]" id="hiddeninput_tags">
```

but it should be like this -

```
<input type="text" style="display:block" value='[{text: " science"},{text:="" "biology"},{text:="" "chemistry"},{text:="" "physics"}]' id="hiddeninput_tags">
```

now you can easily get the tag value.

Comment: that does not solve the problem, but thanks anyway.

Comment: so what do you want to do exactly? r u trying to check exist or not in database that tags?

Comment: No I'm trying to load every tag that's inside a for each to the value of the input.